# Angularjs filter by month by the last 12 months from 1 select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data that I wish to filter this is working fine with 2 separate inputs but I am trying to combine to a single select with the month and the year form the last 12 months.

these then populate a service call eg.:

url.com?month=1&year=2015

Currently I have the following

```
var date = new Date();
var months = [],
monthNames = [ "January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    months.push(monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
}
$scope.months = months;
```

That populate the select box:

```
   <select id="transMonth" name="transMonth" ng-model="month" class="form-control" ng-options="currMonth as currMonth for currMonth in months" ng-change="fetchTransactions()">
        <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
   </select>
```

This currently binds to a the single property 'month' with the value as month name year (eg January 2014) I need to split this and change to a numerical value ie 1 2014

How do I go about this?

Comment: Maybe change `months` to an array of objects? The objects could look something like {month: 1, year: 2014}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

JS:

```
      var date = new Date();
      var months = [],
      monthNames = [ "January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
      for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
          months.push({value: monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear(), id: {month: date.getMonth(), year: date.getFullYear()} });
          date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
      }
$scope.months = months;
```

HTML:

```
  <select id="transMonth" name="transMonth" ng-model="month" class="form-control" ng-options="currMonth.id as currMonth.value for currMonth in months" ng-change="fetchTransactions()">
        <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
   </select>
   {{month}}
```

Comment: Seems to be getting closer to what I need currently $scope.month and $scope.year are the values in the api's url ie url.com?month=$scope.month&year=$scope.year can I split this result so it can pass the values to these? I will probably need to change the ng-model to something else.

Comment: You can just do `url.com?month=$scope.month.month&year=$scope.month.year`